# Scala: How to mix up two List in proportion and in order

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to define a function like this:
`def mixUp[A](lista: List[A], aprop: Int, listb: List[A], bprop: Int): List[A]`

`lista` and `listb` are two List that has the same generic.

And the `aprop`,`bprop` meaning the proportion of `lista` and `listb` that appears.

---

Assume

```
val lista = List("1", "2", "3")
val listb = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
```

Then the result of calling `mixUp(lista, 1, listb, 2)` should be
`List("1", "a", "b", "2", "c", "d", "3", "e", "f")`

---

And if

```
val lista = List("1", "2")
val listb = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

The result of `mixUp(lista, 1, listb, 2)` should be
`List("1", "a", "b", "2", "c", "d", "e")`

---

If

```
val lista = List("1", "2", "3", "4")
val listb = List("a", "b", "c")
```

The result of `mixUp(lista, 1, listb, 2)` should be
`List("1", "a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "4")`

How to implement the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def mix[A](lista: List[A], aprop: Int, listb: List[A], bprop: Int): List[A] = 
  lista.grouped(aprop).zipAll(listb.grouped(bprop), List(), List()).flatMap(t => t._1 ++ t._2).toList
```

Use `grouped` to split the `List` by `size`, and `zipAll` with default empty `List()` to keep all results are same size, `flatMap` to `flatten` map and concat the `tuple`.

**Result:**

```
scala> mix(lista, 1, listb, 2)
res8: List[AnyVal] = List(1, a, b, 2, c, d, 3)

scala> mix(lista, 2, listb, 2)
res9: List[AnyVal] = List(1, 2, a, b, 3, c, d)

scala> mix(lista, 2, listb, 3)
res10: List[AnyVal] = List(1, 2, a, b, c, 3, d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def mixUp[A]( lista: List[A]
            , aprop: Int
            , listb: List[A]
            , bprop: Int
            , acc: List[A] = List()
            ): List[A] = {
  if (lista.nonEmpty)
    mixUp(listb, bprop, lista.drop(aprop), aprop, acc ++ lista.take(aprop))
  else if (listb.nonEmpty)
    mixUp(listb.drop(bprop), bprop, lista, aprop, acc ++ listb.take(bprop))
  else acc
}
```

Add elements to the accumulator in the proper proportions until you run out of elements.